# Did nvm make firebase disappear?

Tags: node.js, firebase, windows-10, nvm

I use `nvm` manage `node.js` versions. Today I installed version 10 which I believe is supported by `firebase`:

```
nvm install 10.16.3
nvm use 10.16.3
```

Then to my surpise the `firebase` command is gone:

```
firebase serve
'firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

It this a known bug in `nvm`? Or is there something else that is wrong? (This is on Windows 10.)

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase CLI is not part of node, npm, or nvm. After you install a new node version, you will have to install the Firebase CLI in that new version with the usual:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why `firebase-tools` is not there any more. Doing `npm list -g` there are other things that are still there.

Comment: If you look at the location where the `firebase` command actually lives, you'll see it's in a per-node-version directory dedicate for global installs for that version.  So, when you install a new node version, you'll need to install the CLI again to place it in its new dedicated space for global installs.  On unix type systems you can run `which firebase` to see where it's it.  Don't know what the equivalent is on Windows.

Comment: @DougStevenson: As a 25 year Windows veteran before switching to Macs, I immediately knew that: `where firebase`. Also see https://superuser.com/questions/207707/what-is-windows-equivalent-of-the-which-command-in-unix-is-there-an-equivale